# Starting from a specific Vertex (@rid) and find specific connected Class

Tags: orientdb

I have this Schema :

```
Regles -Pertinent-> Rubrique
Cri -Pertinent->Rubrique
```

First,

The following command :

```
 SELECT in('Pertinent').@class FROM Rubrique WHERE @rid = '#33:1'
```

return :

```
["Cri","Cri","Cri","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle","Regle"]
```

---

I want to select a specific Vertex with something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Rubrique WHERE @rid = '#33:1'
```

And then select all the connected 'Cri', so i tried this but it seems to doesn't work :

```
SELECT expand(in('Pertinent')) FROM Rubrique WHERE @rid = '#33:1' AND in('Pertinent').@class = "Cri"
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with

```
SELECT expand(in('Pertinent')) FROM Rubrique WHERE @rid = '#33:1' AND in('Pertinent').@class in "Cri"
```

**EDIT**

You could try with

```
SELECT expand(in('Pertinent')[@class = "Cri"]) FROM Rubrique WHERE @rid = '#33:1'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello,
It seems to doesn't work.. It returns both 'Regle' and 'Cri'.

Comment: I will try to reproduce your structure and let you know

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot ! :)